# Is there a way to do concurrent editing?

Tags: 7

Is there a MediaWiki-like method for supporting concurrent editing of text bodies in Drupal 7?

If no feature currently exists, what are some decent PHP diff libraries that could be wrapped up by a Drupal module that could do the job?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [etherpad](http://drupal.org/project/etherpad) kind of feature which allows you to do concurrent edit of node body.

Etherpad is collaborative editor by which you can write any node field using concurrent editing. Check [Readme.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/etherpad.git/blob_plain/0002ecc005a952923d1707f751059c91cc2dcee3:/README) for installation purpose.

And one more thing if you have no permission to install etherpad on your server(as shared hosting will not allow it) then you can use [Piratepad](http://drupal.org/project/piratepad) module, which allows you to embed the pad using iframe from piratepad site.

Comment: PiratePad is for D6, but +1

Comment: But i have ported to Drupal 7 with titanpad integration, but haven't posted on Drupal.org. if any one interested let me know, i can mail you

Comment: Yes please go ahead. Open Sandbox.